# How do I print variables Automatically on python?

Tags: python

I want print variables Automatically like this

```
temp[0] = 1
temp[1] = 2
temp[2] = 3
temp[3] = 4

for i in range(len(temp)):
    print(temp[i])
```

Attempt to print a variable not an array.

```
conv2_1_dw = "some contents"
conv2_1_sep = "some contents"
conv2_2_dw = "some contents"
conv2_2_sep = "some contents"
conv3_1_dw= "some contents"
conv3_1_sep = "some contents"
conv3_2_dw = "some contents"
conv3_2_sep = "some contents"

print(conv2_1_dw)
print(conv2_1_sep)
print(conv2_2_dw)
print(conv2_2_sep)
print(conv3_1_dw)
print(conv3_1_sep)
print(conv3_2_dw)
print(conv3_2_sep)
```

it is difficult to print them one by one.

this is not an array, so i cannot use the for statement.

How to print it Automatically. thank you

Comment: do their names follow a pattern?

Comment: what do you mean by continuously? Do you want to print them at the same time as they are defined, or keep printing them for a number of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind of answered it yourself, the solution is to store the variables in an iterable so you can use an iteration to print them. Or if all of your variables start with `conv` you could rig something up using `locals`. Assuming this is what you mean.

```py
variables = locals()

for name, value in variables.items():
    if name.startswith('conv'):
        print(name, value)
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct but  i got error
'
  File "asdfasdf.py", line 8, in <module>
    for name, value in variables.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
'
how to fix it

Comment: Hmm it does work for me. Try changing the variables assignment to ```variables = locals().copy()```

Answer (score 0):

print command can have many argument on input.
So u can use it like so:

```
var1 = "ab"
var2 = "ac"
print(var1, var2)
```

To print those in separate lines, use it like this:

```
print(var1, var2, sep='\n')
```

Of course sep can be set on whatever you want to be between your variables and '\n' stand for the new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
conv2_1_dw = "some contents"
conv2_1_sep = "some contents"
conv2_2_dw = "some contents"
conv2_2_sep = "some contents"
conv3_1_dw= "some contents"
conv3_1_sep = "some contents"
conv3_2_dw = "some contents"
conv3_2_sep = "some contents"

while True:
  print(conv2_1_dw)
  print(conv2_1_sep)
  print(conv2_2_dw)
  print(conv2_2_sep)
  print(conv3_1_dw)
  print(conv3_1_sep)
  print(conv3_2_dw)
  print(conv3_2_sep)
```